# Cost of parameter passing in webgl pixel shaders?

Tags: webgl, pixel-shader, efficiency

In a webgl pixel shader, all functions are inlined as i understand it, however you can have parameters that are marked as ***in*** versus being ***inout*** meaning that their value can change but the value won't persist outside of the function call.

Does this mean that the shader must make a copy of the value for the function to work with when it is an ***in*** value?

Are shader compilers/optimizers smart enough to know when they don't need to make a copy, or is it best to really just mark up all parameters as ***inout*** and make sure and not modify the ones you don't want modified, if performance is the primary concern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My experience working with shader compiler stacks a few years back is that they are extremely aggressive, and I doubt you will see any perf difference, but I would suggest testing as much as you can.

I would generally recommend providing the compiler (and human readers) with more information where the language allows it, marking parameters according to their usage. Treating an in-only parameter as in/out is more error prone for humans than compilers.

Some detail: shaders run almost entirely using registers for variables (I worked with architectures that supported up to 256 32 bit registers) - spilling is hugely expensive. Physical registers are shared between shader invocations - think of this as threads in a HyperThread sense sharing a register pool - and if the shader can be complied to use fewer registers there's greater parallelism. The result is shader compilers work very hard to minimize the number of registers used - without spilling, of course. Thus inlining is common since it's desirable to optimize register allocation across the whole shader anyway.